# Why does my sjoin() return me an emtpy GeoDataFrame?

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to make a join between two GeoDataFrame.

The first one gathers the coordinates of points associated with a name.
The second one is a set of polygons based on the French cadastre.

I would like to be able to join the two GeoDataFrame based on their geographical relationships.

Based on an inner join, the names Melynn and Gaspard should be returned because they are associated with coordinates included in the polygons.

NB :They have the same crs : "EPSG:2154"

The first GeoDataFrame :

```
data{'Noms (z)'['Melynn','Paul','David','Gaspard'],'lat'[49.46138,49.4404591,49.4404591, 49.46138], 'long':[1.07948,1.0939658,1.0939658, 1.07948]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

pts=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['lat'],df['long'],crs="EPSG:2154"))
```

The second GeoDataFrame :

```
shapes = gpd.read_file("..\Data sets\cadastre-76-sections-shp\sections.shp")

subshapes = shapes[shapes['commune']=='76451']
```

The joint :

```
gpd.sjoin(pts, subshapes, how="inner", op="within")
```

This inner joint only return me an empty GeoDataFrame...

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! check out the guide to [ask]. you seem to be calling these functions correctly, and the functions do work, so they must not be actually overlapping spatially. we don't have enough information to help, but that's my guess. have you tried plotting them on the same axes to make sure that they do overlap? or maybe try manually inspecting the `.bounds` bounding boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a good night's sleep, I realized that my points were WGS84 (EPSG:4326) based coordinates so I had set them wrong.

I changed the coordinates and everything worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).